# java finding the sum of a 2d square grid

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm writing code that tries to find the sum of a 2 dimensional array:

```
int gridSum(int[][] grid) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < grid.length;r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < grid.length; c++){
            total += grid [r][c];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

This runs, but if I input values other than where the sum is zero, or when there is only one value, it returns the wrong sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] multi = new int[][]{
                {1, 2},
                {3, 4, 5},
                {6, 7, 8, 9}
        };

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < multi.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < multi[i].length; j++) {
                sum += multi[i][j];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Output will be 45.